# AngularJS cannot call method 'get' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I started writing AngularJS files this morning, and within four hours, due to my poor experience with it and with JavaScript, mistakes just keep showing up.

This one I just cannot debug by myself.

This is my controller script:

```
angular.module('organHome', ['organResource'])

  .controller('organPageCtrl', function ($scope, Magazines, Organizations, OrganComments) {
    //It needs magazines, comments

        $scope.organization = Organizations.get(); //from url
        $scope.magazines = Magazines.query();
        $scope.comments = OrganComments.query();
  });
```

I have a different module storing code that connects to backend api:

```
angular.module('organResource', ['ngResource'])

  .factory('Organizations', function ($resource) {

    var url = document.URL;
    var urlArray = url.split("/");
    var organId = urlArray[urlArray.length-1];

    return 
    $resource('http://localhost/dooleystand/ci/api/organization/:id', {
        loginID : organEntity,
        password : organCommpassword, 
        id : organId
    });
  });
```

All my database connection methods look the same.

Then I get an error from console saying: **TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined**

And it points to this line of my controller code:

```
$scope.organization = Organizations.get();
```

I checked my backend code, it should be fine. I convert one PHP array into json format, which should be a javascript object. Why is it saying that "get" of undefined?

Comment: I'm not sure how you set the id in the URL of your resource. Usually, you would use `get` with an `id` parameter that would be replaced by angular in the url where `:id` is in the string. Maybe your could try to do in your controller `Organisations.get({id: $routeParams.id})` to send the id.

Comment: Try using this format to pass in the services:

`.controller('organPageCtrl', function ('$scope', 'Magazines', 'Organizations', 'OrganComments') {
  function($scope, Magazines, Organizations, OrganComments) {
...
`

Comment: I think the format should be: `.controller('organPageCtrl', ['$scope', 'Magazines', 'Organizations', 'OrganComments', function($scope, Magazines, Organizations, OrganComments) { ... }]);`

Comment: @jpmorin I'll try the format. The id is extracted out of the url.

Comment: And I would try to include the `ngResource` into your `organHome` module.

Comment: I don't think that the format of your controller is wrong, but the alternative is good practice.

Comment: @jpmorin No it's not the format's fault. I added ngResource to organHome module before. It's not the cause.

Comment: Are all your files included? Just to be sure :)

Comment: @jpmorin Yes they are! Btw the good news is the other two lines: getmagazines and getcomments work just fine! I tried `Organizations.query()` and it was not working as well.

Comment: A really small hidden thing might be different between your services. Hardest to debug.

Comment: @jpmorin YOU ARE A SAINT! So right!! I didn't think it would be a problem, but it clearly is. The return clause inside my Organization factory has a line break between return and $resource instead of just return $resource(); Thank you! Problem solved!

Comment: This is a nice to know tip!